# C# equivalent for Java's AbstractProcessor

Tags: c#, annotations

First of all, I made my own java library and I want to use it into generated Classes at build time using AbstractProcessor. The idea is that I make an interface, annotate it with my own annotation and then my own AbstractProcessor will find that interface (using annotation) and implement it. So I can use that class without creating it(the abstract processor will do that for me).

Now I want to make the exact same thing in C#. I want to create an attribute(the c# version of annotation), then create an interface with that attribute, and then create something like an AbstractProcessor that can find that interface and implement it at build time.

Comment: Am i missing something, create a custom attribute based on the attribute class, decorate an interface with it, then use reflection to look for it?

Comment: Yes. Something like that. I do not know how exactly the attributes really work in C#, but I heard that they are the same as java annotations.. so i though that I can use them in the same way.

Comment: I am not a Java Jedi, so ill leave this to someone who understands AbstractProcessor